# Finding largest integer of four inputs using MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to print the largest integer of four inputs from the user. I figured out how to do it up to three integers, but the last CMP I am having difficulties with. I need assistance with the last CMP.

I am assuming I need one more CMP to solve this issue, but everything I try always just prints out the largest of the first three numbers.

```
    # this program prints out the four of two numbers 
# The four numbers are read through the keyboard 
.text
.globl main

main:
# Display prompt1
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

# read keyboard into $v0 (number x is number to test)
li $v0, 5
syscall

# move the first number from $v0 in $t0
move $t0,$v0

# Display the prmopt2 (string)
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

# read keyboard into $v0 
li $v0, 5 
syscall

# move the second number from $v0 in $t1
move $t1,$v0 

# Display the prmopt3 (string)
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3
syscall

# read keyboard into $v0 
li $v0, 5 
syscall

# move the third number from $v0 in $t2
move $t2,$v0

# Display the prmopt4 (string)
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt4
syscall

# read keyboard into $v0 
li $v0, 5 
syscall

# move the fourth number from $v0 in $t3
move $t3,$v0


# effectively these two lines do: $t1 = max($t0, $t1)
bge $t1, $t0, CMP2
move $t1, $t0

CMP2:
# effectively these two lines do: $t1 = max($t2, $t1)
bge $t1, $t2, L1 
move $t1, $t2

# largest number in $t1  
move $t2, $t0       

# print answer 
L1: 
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, answer
syscall

# print integer function call 1 
# put the answer into $a0
li $v0, 1 
move $a0, $t1 
syscall

#exit
end: li $v0, 10 
syscall 

.data
prompt1:
 .asciiz "Enter the first number "
prompt2:
 .asciiz "Enter the second number "
prompt3:
 .asciiz "Enter the third number "
prompt4:
 .asciiz "Enter the fourth number "
answer:
 .asciiz "The largest number is "
```

The actual results spit out the largest of the three numbers. I need the actual results of the largest of four integers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you tried? It's not making sense "tried everything"... implies there is no solution.... that's why you posted the question, right?! Just update the question. NO need for people to down-vote.

Comment: I figured it out, but I appreciate the feedback on how to properly ask the question. Thanks.

Comment: ... I hate the suspense tension of having to wait to see your answer... "post your self-gained insight on solving your own communicated mystery a.s.a.p...." ;p

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution on mine own. This was the snippet of code that I was in need of...

```
CMP1:
# the following lines perform this: $t1 = max($t0, $t1)
bge $t1, $t0, CMP2
move $t1, $t0

CMP2:
# the following lines perform this: $t1 = max($t2, $t1)
bge $t1, $t2, L1 
move $t1, $t2

# the following lines perform this: $t1 = max($t3, $t2)
CMP3:
bge $t1, $t3, CMP2
move $t1, $t3
```