# Find the largest number and average in MIPs stack

Tags: stack, compare, mips

I've been struggling to find the largest number in the stack in this project. I've been able to get the accurate average just fine but the value of the largest is inaccurate. It's often either 1 or 11. Any ideas?

The output currently looks like:

> Enter first number: 2

> Enter second number: 4

> Enter third number: 5

> Enter fourth number: 2

> The average is: 3The largest is: 11

```
 .data
    prompt1: .asciiz "Enter first number: "
    prompt2: .asciiz "Enter second number: "
    prompt3: .asciiz "Enter third number: "
    prompt4: .asciiz "Enter fourth number: "
    largest: .asciiz "The largest is: "
    average: .asciiz "The average is: "
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"

.text
#Subprogram largestAndAverage($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4)
#{
#   int var0 = $a0, var1 = $a1, var2 = $a2, var3 = $a3;
#   $s0 = getLarger($a1, $a2);
#   $v0 = getLarager(s0, $a4); // Largest is in $v0
#   $v1 = (var0 + var1 + var2 + var3)/ 4; // (Integer) Average is in $v1
#   return;
#}

#Subprogram getLarger($a0, $a1) {
#   $v0 = $a0
#   if ($a1 > $a0)
#   $v0 = $a1
#   return;
#}

.globl main

main:
    # register conventions
    # $s0 - num1
    # $s1 - num2
    # $s2 - num3
    # $s3 - num4
    # $s4 - largest
    # $s5 - average
    
    # TODO: First numb
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
    
    move $s0, $v0
    
    # TODO: Second numb
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
    
    move $s1, $v0
    
    # TODO: Third numb
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt3
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
    
    move $s2, $v0
    
    # TODO: Fourth numb
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt4
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
    
    move $s3, $v0
    
    # TODO: Call Function
    # .......
    jal Largest_Avg
    # .......
    
    # TODO: Print the largest
    
    # TODO:  Print average
    
    jal Exit

###############################################################
# YOUR PRECEDURES HERE ...........
###############################################################

Largest_Avg:
    #load registers
    la  $a0,($s0)
    la  $a1,($s1)
    la  $a2,($s2)
    la  $a3,($s3)
    
    bgt $a0,$a1,getLarger
    
    #calculate average
    add $t1,$a0,$a1
    add $t2,$a2,$a3
    add $t3,$t1,$t2
    
    addi $t4, $zero, 4
    div $v1,$t3,$t4
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, average
    
    syscall
    
    li $v0,1 
    add $a0, $zero, $v1
    syscall
    
getLarger:
    la  $t5,($a0)
    la  $t6,($a1)
    bgt $t5,$t6,print_num
    
    move $v0,$t5
        
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, largest
    syscall
    
    li $v0,1 
    add $a0, $zero, $v0
    syscall
        
print_num:
    li $v0,1
    la $a0,($v0)
    syscall 

###############################################################
.include "utils.asm"
```

Comment: What do you observe when single stepping?

Comment: It all seems ok until after line 136 then it starts recalling line 30 and it fills registers $a0 and $v0 with long variable values outside of those provided by the user

Comment: Why is printing the number part of the `getLarger` function? Also, `getLarger` currently falls down into whatever happens to come after it in memory since you don't jump anywhere. And please don't use `la` to copy the value of one register to another; there's a perfectly good instruction for that called `move`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Did some changes and then a little more digging and got it done. This really helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328486/finding-largest-integer-of-four-inputs-using-mips-assembly